# react-router-dom Prompt never shows

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a React Route with significant user input that I want to use the Prompt component with. I'm importing it from react-router-dom without error and adding the component to the render method of the class component, but no matter what, the prompt alert never actually appears and the user can freely navigate off the page without seeing any alert.

I've tried:

- Putting the component in with when={aStateBooleanVariable} as well as when={true} and no when attribute at all.
- Using a function for the message.
- Ensuring that the Route it's on is an exact path.
- Importing it from react-router instead of react-router-dom.
- Moving the component around within the render method.
- Moving the Prompt into the actual Switch statement itself in the App component that wraps everything in BrowserRouter.

Nothing I've tried has gotten the prompt to actually show up or prevent the user from navigating off the page and I've been unable to find anything in the docs or extensive searching where anyone else has had this problem. Does anyone have any idea why this just isn't even starting to work?

I'm not really sure what code to put since it's all pretty much boilerplate react-router-dom.

This is my App.jsx switch statement:

```
return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <header>
                {loggedInUser ? <NavbarComp loggedInUser={loggedInUser} setLoggedInUser={setLoggedInUser} /> : null}
            </header>
            <Switch>
                <PrivateRoute path="/ged/campaigns/new" component={CampaignNew} loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/ged/campaigns/:id" component={Campaign} loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/ged/characters/new" component={CharGen} loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/ged/characters/:id" component={CharacterMain} loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/ged" component={GEDHome} loggedInUser={loggedInUser} />} />
                <Route path="/" component={Home} loggedInUser={loggedInUser} setLoggedInUser={setLoggedInUser} />} />
                <Route component={DeadPage} />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

I'm importing the component as:

`import {Prompt} from 'react-router-dom';`

And incorporating the component at the top of its parent's render method return:

`<Prompt message="You have changes that will be lost if you leave without saving." />`

What other code might be making it fail silently like this?

Comment: share code please for better understanding of the problem

Comment: could you reproduce you case here https://codesandbox.io/?